# what command will show my zone address books?

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-srx

`# show security address-book` displays the global address books.

But I have no global address books I have zone address books. Is there no show command that displays this?
I can see it in the GUI:

[image]

I can do a `# show security zones` to just get a complete dump of the config of course. I guess I'm not really clear on the difference or why you would create a zone address book instead of a global one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
show security zones security-zone <zone-name> address-book
```

Comment: that works, but is there a way to get the address books for all zone? I cant use a wildcard in place of the zone name

Comment: @red888 try this one: `show security zones | match address-book | display set`